# En fetch dónde poner el HASH y la API Key

Tags: javascript, fetch

Hola tengo el siguiente código

```
export default function getCharacters (){
    return fetch(`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=9&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${HASH}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
         .then(json =>{
             console.log(json)
         })
}
```

Hay alguna manera de poner la public key y el hash en el metodo del fetch, que no este dentro de la url como lo tengo en el código? Al estilo que puedes poner el method por ejemplo.

Comment: Lo podrías colocar en los headers, pero eso depende más de cómo es que te lo pida tu api, que de cómo lo desees tú en realidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que te refieres es a un constructor de parámetros, para no concatenarlos directamente en la URL, puedes usar la clase [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
    ts: 9,
    apikey: PUBLIC_KEY,
    hash: HASH
});

fetch('http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?' + queryParams);
```

De hecho es la forma más recomendable, pues esa clase se encarga de codificar correctamente los caracteres inválidos para una URL.

Comment: Eso buscaba, gracias